# Formula for $\arg_{\alpha}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Define for $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ the complex function $\arg_{\alpha}$ which assigns to $z$ the unique value of $\arg z$ in $[\alpha, \alpha + 2\pi)$.

Why is true that for any $z$,

$$\arg_{\alpha}(z) = \operatorname{Arg}(z e^{i(\pi - \alpha)}) + \pi + \alpha$$

where $\text{Arg}$ is the principal argument function which I define it to be the argument of $z$ in $[-\pi, \pi)$. Thanks.

Comment: "Magical" formula?  You said that the "Arg" part gives a value in $[-\pi, \pi)$.  So using the periodicity of the function what do you need to do to get the value in $[\alpha, \alpha+ 2\pi)$?

Comment: @user247327 ok. it is not magical. but I am looking for some explanation for why this is true, and how it was thought out.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta={\rm Arg}(ze^{i(\pi-\alpha)})$. You have
$$-\pi\le\theta<\pi\ .$$
To find $\arg_\alpha(z)$ you need to

- add $\alpha-\pi$ so that you are looking at the argument of $z$ and not of something else; this gives
  $$\alpha-2\pi\le\theta+\alpha-\pi<\alpha\ ;$$
- add $2\pi$ to get it into the range you want:
  $$\alpha\le\theta+\alpha+\pi<\alpha+2\pi\ .$$

So $\theta+\alpha+\pi$ is the argument you want.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication by the exponential increases the argument by $\pi-\alpha$. Adding $\pi+\alpha$ increases it by $\pi+\alpha$, so mod $2\pi$ the expression gives arg $z$. Since Arg lies in the range $-\pi$ to $\pi$, after adding $\pi+\alpha$ the result must lie in the range $\alpha$ to $\alpha+2\pi$.